# download csv from react app which created by rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, csv

I have a download button on the client side which uses react js. 
On click of that button, I call a rails api, this rails api, generates csv on local storage.

Is is possible to pass that generated csv file as a response to react, which will then auto-download that file. CSV generation and the download should be done on single click of Download button.